# How can I get our application pod logs to the aws cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, kubernetes-pod, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to get my running applications pod logs in the AWS cloud watch .I got some reference from the youtube

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPCS8jBqmQk

They used fluentd and all .Once after you aware of the video ,Please check the workflow which is used

> https://github.com/RekhuGopal/PythonHacks/blob/main/AWS_EKS_Logs_to_CloudwatchLoggroups/CommandFiles.json
>
> https://github.com/RekhuGopal/PythonHacks/tree/main/AWS_EKS_Logs_to_CloudwatchLoggroups

Do check once, like they got kube-system logs to the cloudwatch , but I need the applications logs to the cloud watch.That is while we go with this command through terminal,

```
kubectl logs -f (pod name with id)
```

**logs will list**
that logs what I get in the terminal(powershell) that I wants to be listed in cloudwatch. For integration, make a reference of the video. Thanks in advance.
I think I need to edit the configmap file

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  containers.conf: |
    <source>
      @type tail
      @id in_tail_container_logs
      @label @containers
      path /var/log/containers/*.log
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
      tag *
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
        @type json
        time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
      </parse>
    </source>

    <label @containers>
      <filter **>
        @type kubernetes_metadata
        @id filter_kube_metadata
      </filter>

      <filter **>
        @type record_transformer
        @id filter_containers_stream_transformer
        <record>
          stream_name ${tag_parts[3]}
        </record>
      </filter>

      <match **>
        @type cloudwatch_logs
        @id out_cloudwatch_logs_containers
        region "#{ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')}"
        log_group_name "/k8s-nest/#{ENV.fetch('AWS_EKS_CLUSTER_NAME')}/containers"
        log_stream_name_key stream_name
        remove_log_stream_name_key true
        auto_create_stream true
        <buffer>
          flush_interval 5
          chunk_limit_size 2m
          queued_chunks_limit_size 32
          retry_forever true
        </buffer>
      </match>
    </label>
  fluent.conf: |
    @include containers.conf
    @include systemd.conf

    <match fluent.**>
      @type null
    </match>
  systemd.conf: |
    <source>
      @type systemd
      @id in_systemd_kubelet
      @label @systemd
      filters [{ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "kubelet.service" }]
      <entry>
        field_map {"MESSAGE": "message", "_HOSTNAME": "hostname", "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "systemd_unit"}
        field_map_strict true
      </entry>
      path /run/log/journal
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-journald-kubelet.pos
      read_from_head true
      tag kubelet.service
    </source>

    <source>
      @type systemd
      @id in_systemd_kubeproxy
      @label @systemd
      filters [{ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "kubeproxy.service" }]
      <entry>
        field_map {"MESSAGE": "message", "_HOSTNAME": "hostname", "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "systemd_unit"}
        field_map_strict true
      </entry>
      path /run/log/journal
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-journald-kubeproxy.pos
      read_from_head true
      tag kubeproxy.service
    </source>

    <source>
      @type systemd
      @id in_systemd_docker
      @label @systemd
      filters [{ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "docker.service" }]
      <entry>
        field_map {"MESSAGE": "message", "_HOSTNAME": "hostname", "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "systemd_unit"}
        field_map_strict true
      </entry>
      path /run/log/journal
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-journald-docker.pos
      read_from_head true
      tag docker.service
    </source>

    <label @systemd>
      <filter **>
        @type record_transformer
        @id filter_systemd_stream_transformer
        <record>
          stream_name ${tag}-${record["hostname"]}
        </record>
      </filter>

      <match **>
        @type cloudwatch_logs
        @id out_cloudwatch_logs_systemd
        region "#{ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')}"
        log_group_name "/k8s-nest/#{ENV.fetch('AWS_EKS_CLUSTER_NAME')}/systemd"
        log_stream_name_key stream_name
        auto_create_stream true
        remove_log_stream_name_key true
        <buffer>
          flush_interval 5
          chunk_limit_size 2m
          queued_chunks_limit_size 32
          retry_forever true
        </buffer>
      </match>
    </label>
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-cloudwatch
  name: fluentd-config
  namespace: stellacenter-dev
```

The namespace which I used , which my application pods are running.Thanks in advance